# Is there any alternative of writing a click function on all elements in angular

Tags: angular

[code screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Mbu.png)
[image]

[code screenshots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtmcM.png)

[image]

In this picture you can see there are five(5) `li` elements and all have that one function, but what if these `li` elements are in a large number so  I just want to shorten the way to write this function and attach it to all these `li` element in angular.

Comment: Please take a look:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6294072

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have 5 clickable list items with every single one doing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the function to the parent `<ul>` and it will be invoked for each click on the child `<li>`.

Reason: events propagate towards the root of the HTML document unless they are cancelled.

Excerpts from working example:

app.component.html

```
<ul (click)="sampleClick()">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public  sampleClick(){
    console.log('!')
  }
}
```

Full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlrxpt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html